# How to record discounts in a shop?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been thinking about this for a while now, but I am still not sure as the best way to go about it.

So basically, in my online shop I have an `order` table:

```
+------+-------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------+
|  id  | name  |  email  | grand-total | shipping-costs |   address    | status |
+------+-------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------+
| 4312 | Roger | r@g.com | 5.99        |              1 | 22 Road Lane |      1 |
+------+-------+---------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------+
```

And linked to that table is the `cart` table:

```
+-----+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+--------+
| id  | orderID | productID |     name      | price | quantity | status |
+-----+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+--------+
| 234 |    4312 | G55Sd     | Super Product | 5.99  |        1 |      1 |
+-----+---------+-----------+---------------+-------+----------+--------+
```

This all works correctly. However, the problem comes when I want to start adding discounts.  I want to be able to look at a past order, and know exactly what discount was applied, how much etc.  But I don't know where to save it.  And what if the customer has multiple discounts? I can't just add another column in the `orders` table for discount, or discount amount, as that wouldn't help future me look over it at all.

I was thinking maybe I could add a line in the `cart` table for that order, and apply it like a product, just with a minus amount.  I could do with some advice please.

Comment: You can keep the discounts in another separate table according to order.

Comment: create new table `discounts` to keep all discount types and second table `discounts_to_otders` (many-to-many) where you can apply one or more discounts on particular order.

Comment: I was thinking that, but then how would such a table be laid out?

Comment: @Chud37, not sure what do you mean?

Comment: how would you build that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful you don't over-normalise. Disk is cheap - I would consider holding discount details in the order table and the cart table. The business logic could  be every product might accrue a discount and the order itself might have a discount on top of the product discount(s).